# Is it a bad practice to use cookies for a Desktop Application?

Tags: desktop-application, cookies, load-balancing

I'm working on a Desktop App in C# that communicates with a Java backend hosted AWS.
I want to deploy on multiple instances and use an Application Load Balancer with sticky sessions but as Far as I know it is based on cookies to route the request.

So far I can only think on 2 solutions :

1. Handle cookies on my Desktop App, so my question if it is a bad practice
2. Create my own load balancer on a different instance and route based on an http header.

I would like your opinion about these 2 solutions, which one do you think complies the most with good practices.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In principle, there's no problem with using HTTP/REST to communicate between a desktop app and a backend. In that context, it can also be a great idea to use various HTTP features. This might include cookies, though your client code will probably not implement a full-fledged “cookie jar”. And it would be unusual to create a backend API that expects you to use cookies, with `Authorization: Bearer TOKEN` headers being more common.

What is a bad practice though is sticky sessions. You might want to use sticky sessions when your backend has multiple instances for load-balancing, and each instance stores its own per-session data, in particular if that per-session data is stored in memory. This leads to a host of problems, notably that sessions are logged out if you need to restart an instance, that you can't scale up or down easily, and that it's not fault-tolerant.

Industry best practice very clearly is that such backend instances should be stateless – if they need to persist any data beyond a request, that data should be externalized into a database. Then, you can freely load balance without having to consider which instance handled which session. Consider reading [The 12 Factor App](https://12factor.net/), in particular point VI: [Execute the app as one or more stateless processes](https://12factor.net/processes).

I would only consider deviating from this best practice and start using sticky sessions if the API in question is extremely latency sensitive, so that the extra millisecond for connecting to a shared session storage database (e.g. Redis) would be intolerable.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply, for session replication I use tomcat clusters in a multicast membership, this allows me to keep the same session even if the instance starting it is shutdown

Comment: @HichamZouarhi If you use session replication, then you don't need sticky sessions. Note that Tomcat's default session replication is in-memory, and session data will still get lost if the entire cluster shuts down.